# Condition of orthogonal eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> If a matrix $A$ satifies $A^TA=AA^T$, then its eigenvectors are
>   orthogonal.

I have not had a proof for the above statement yet. By the way, by the Singular Value Decomposition, $A=U\Sigma V^T$, and because $A^TA=AA^T$, then $U=V$ (following the constructions of $U$ and $V$). So $A=U\Sigma U^T$, thus $A$ is symmetric since $\Sigma$ is diagonal. In fact, the skew-symmetric or diagonal matrices also satisfy the condition $AA^T=A^TA$. So at which point do I misunderstand the SVD? And please also give me the proof of the statement.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you seen the Schur decomposition? This is the standard tool for proving the spectral theorem for normal matrices.

Comment: Usually the fact that you are trying to prove is used to prove the existence of a matrix's SVD, so your approach would be using the theorem to prove itself.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$
$$
\ker(A) = \ker(A^TA) = \ker(AA^T) = \ker(A^T) = \im(A)^\perp
$$
Similarly, we have $\ker(A - \lambda I) = \im(A - \lambda I)^\perp$.

Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.  Then any corresponding eigenvector lies in $\ker(A - \lambda I)$.  Any eigenvector corresponding to a value other than $\lambda$ lies in $\im(A - \lambda I)$.

Thus, if two eigenvectors correspond to different eigenvalues, then they are orthogonal.

Comment: Where did @Tien go wrong in his SVD Argument? Let's take a skew-symmetric matrix so, $AA^T = A^TA \implies U = V \implies A = A^T$?

Comment: @Shiv As I said in my comment above: this result is typically used to prove the existence of SVD. So, unless one uses a completely different proof of the existence of SVD, this is an inherently circular argument.

Comment: @Shiv Setting that aside (indeed, one can prove the existence of SVD without the use of the spectral theorem), we have $AA^T = A^TA \implies V^T\Sigma^2 V = U^T \Sigma^2 U$, but it is not immediately clear from this that $U = V$. It is also very strange that you somehow ended up with $A = A^T$ in your comment.

Comment: I used the definition that $U$ contains eigenvectors of $AA^T$ and $V$ contains eigenvectors of $A^TA$. Thus, I feel they should be same. I am not very familiar with proof of SVD and when it works. Will be more than happy if you can point me to that and clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

SVD of a $m \times n$ matrix $A$ aims to figure out orthonormal basis $\{v_{1},v_{2},\dots, v_{r}\}$ of row space, which are mapped to orthogonal basis $\{Av_{1},Av_{2},\dots, Av_{r}\}$ of column space. Here $r$ is the rank of the matrix $A$.
**Claim**: Selecting $v_{i}$s as eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$  with eigenvalues $\lambda_{i} \neq 0 $ satisfies this aim.
**Proof**: First, we prove that $v_{i}$s are indeed orthonormal basis of row space
$v_{i} \notin Ker(A^{T}A)$ because eigenvalue of $v_{i}$ is not zero.
Also $Ker(A^{T}A)=Ker(A)$. So $v_{i} \notin Ker(A)$.
$Ker(A)$ and $row \ space(A)$ are orthogonal compliment of each other which follows $v_{i} \in row\ space(A)$.
And one can span complete row space by $v_{i}$s, since $A^{T}A$ will have full set of eigenvectors.
$n-r$ eigenvectors have eigenvalue $0$, while other $r$ orthonormal eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ with non zero eigenvalues  are basis of row space

Now we need to show that all $v_{i}$s are mapped to orthogonal basis of column space by $A$. So we need to prove that $Av_{i}$ is orthogonal to $Av_{j}$ whenever $i \neq j$.
\begin{align}
(Av_{i})^{T}(Av_{j}) & = v_{i}^{T}A^{T}Av_{j}\\
& = v_{i}^{T}(A^{T}Av_{j})\\
& = v_{i}^{T}(\lambda_{j}v_{j})\quad (v_{j}\ is\ an\ eigenvector\ of\ A^{T}A)\\
&= 0\quad (v_{i}\ is\ orthogonal\ to\ v_{j})
\end{align}
**Proof ends here.**

Now let us define $u_{i}=\frac{Av_{i}}{\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}}$.(which is ith column of matrix $U$.) **Surprisingly** these $u_{i}$s turn out to be eigenvectors of $AA^{T}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$. Because
\begin{align}
AA^{T}u_{i} & = AA^{T}\frac{Av_{i}}{\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}}\\
& = A\frac{(A^{T}Av_{i})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}}\\
& = A\frac{(\lambda_{i}v_{i})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}}\\
&= \lambda_{i}\left(\frac{Av_{i}}{\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}}\right)\\
&= \lambda_{i}u_{i}\\
\end{align}

So it's correct that $U$ and $V$ contains eigenvectors of $AA^{T}$ and $A^{T}A$ respectively. But we can see that after fixing $v_{i}$s as eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$, the only way to get $u_{i}$ is $u_{i}=\frac{Av_{i}}{\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}}$. 
So if $A^{T}A=AA^{T}$, then we can select eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ to construct $V$ but then $U$ will be automatically cooked. Definitely $U$ also contains eigenvector of $AA^{T}=A^{T}A$. One can naturally think that both $U$ and $V$ contains eigenvectors of same matrix so they will be same. But one can select eigenvectors of the same matrix differently. And we don't know which set of eigenvectors will be cooked by this constructive algorithm. So $U=V$ is only a special case. Hence provided information is not sufficient to tell that $U=V$

Try to find SVD of a skew-symmetric matrix
\begin{gather}
 A
 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 &
   -1\\
   1 &
   0
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
using mentioned constructive algorithm and see that $V \neq U$, at the same time they contain eigenvectors of $A^{T}A=AA^{T}$.